# ¿Por qué mi codigo arroja la siguiente excepción "Exception caught by animation library"?

Tags: excepciones, flutter, alertdialog

Estoy pasando a una pagina utilizando el `Navigator.pushNamed`, pero eso después de realizar un proceso de descarga de un **PDF**,

Lo primero que hago para mostrar que se esta descargando utilizo un `AlertDialog` que muestra un `CircularProgressIndicator` hasta que finalice la tarea entonces pasara a otra pantalla.

1. Primero realizo la llamada del método que mostrara el `AlertDialog` para indicar que se esta descargando.

al terminar pasara a la pantalla **PDF**

```
print('descargando...');
archivo = await _descargando(ApiService.downPDF(npdf));
print('descarga finalizada');

if (archivo != null) {
    await Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'viewPdf', arguments: archivo.path);
}
```

Método de `_descargando()`, en el cual utilizo `Navigator.of(context).pop();` para cerrar el `AlertDialog` y proceda a continuar con la navegación a otra pantalla.

```
Future _descargando(Future future) async {
    dynamic result;
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Descargando..'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              FutureBuilder(
                future: future,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    result = snapshot.data;
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    );
    return result;
}
```

**Me cambia bien de pantalla y el proceso de descarga se realiza sin problema pero en consola me manda la siguiente excepción.**

```
════════ Exception caught by animation library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while notifying status listeners for AnimationController:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This _ModalScope<dynamic> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: _ModalScope<dynamic>-[LabeledGlobalKey<_ModalScopeState<dynamic>>#78b06]
state: _ModalScopeState<dynamic>#4ff65
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: FutureBuilder<dynamic>
    dirty
    state: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#4506e
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3687
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3702
#2      State.setState 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1161
#3      _ModalScopeState._routeSetState 
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:633
#4      ModalRoute.setState 
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:732
...
The AnimationController notifying status listeners was: AnimationController#97aad(◀ 1.000; for _DialogRoute<dynamic>)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque estás haciendo un rebuild cuando el widget se está refrescando, puedes poner el pop en un método asíncrono:

```
 _dismissWidget(BuildContext myContext) async {
   Future((){
      Navigator.of(myContext).pop();
   });
  }
```

Y el `builder` de tu `FutureBuilder` queda así:

```
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    result = snapshot.data;
                    _dismissWidget(context);
                    return const SizedBox.shrink();
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
```